# Searching with eloquent using string and statuses

Tags: php, eloquent

I need to search through a bunch of landing pages, and return the results. Currently I have this code:

```
/**
 * @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
private $query;

/**
 * @param string $status
 * @param string $search
 * @param int $offset
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function getLandingPageListing($status = 'all', $search = '', $offset = 0)
{
    $this->query = $this->model->newQuery();
    $this->setRelationship();
    $this->setStatus($status);
    $this->setSearch($search);
    return $this->getLandingPages();
}

private function setRelationship()
{
    $this->query->with('message');
}

/**
 * @param string $status
 */
private function setStatus($status)
{
    if ($status !== 'all') {
        $this->query->where('lp_status', $status);
    }
}

/**
 * @param string $search
 */
private function setSearch($search)
{
    if ($search !== '') {
        $this->query->where('lp_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        $this->query->orWhere('lp_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        $this->query->orWhere('lp_domain', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        $this->query->orWhereHas('message', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('message_subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
        });
    }
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
private function getLandingPages()
{
    return $this->query->get();
}
```

If I search something, it returns what I've searched, and if I filter by a status it returns that status which is fine. However, when I filter and search, it doesn't work and only returns the last action.

So let's say I filter by active, it will return all the active landing pages. If I then search 'Example' in those active pages, it will return all 'Examples' and not just those that are active.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query needs parenthesis. Your orWhere methods break your logic and so it returns all page that includes example as result. You can do it by something like this code block.

```
private function setSearch($search)
{
    if ($search !== '') {
        $this->query(function($query) use ($search){
            $query->where('lp_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            $query->orWhere('lp_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            $query->orWhere('lp_domain', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            $query->orWhereHas('message', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('message_subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

You can learn more [here](http://laraveldaily.com/and-or-and-brackets-with-eloquent/) about it.

Comment: This works. However, if I change the filter it doesn't remember the actual search, but I'll play around with it a bit more. Thanks for the assistance. :)